# Is there any possibilities to have native android code?

Tags: java, android, neomad

The question is simple : Is there any possibilities to have native android code on Neomad ? Yes ? How to do that ?

I can have windows phone native code, iOS native code but how to have Android native code ?

when i am compiling my code, i only have .apk for Android ! No native code. Explanation ?

Thank you

Comment: what does *native* mean  for you?s

Comment: I want to have in my Neomad Project the android code source like I have iOS code source, windows phone code source etc..

Comment: the you want the *Android source code*

Comment: @blackbelt yes i want android source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "generate" native Android **project**.

Two way for it:

- By command line: Add generate project option (-gp)
- With Eclipse: In **option** tab of your NeoMAD launch configuration, you have to add "-gp" in **Additional command line** field.

Comment: I am with the plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you dude ! Genius ! You make my day ! It works :)

Answer (score 1):

JNI is the explaination.
Java Native Interface also works under android.
To build it you need NDK though.
Refer to https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Comment: I want to have the native Android code with Neomad.